# Tunelling websockets calls through Apache on TLS to non TLS Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat8

We are using websockets in one of our projects. Our setup has an Apache Web Server and a different server with Tomcat instance. Apache is on TLS but the tomcat instance does not have TLS.
We are trying to tunnel the websockets through the apache (wss) to tomcat instance (ws). 
Is this possible ? The initial handshake is successful and we get a 101 Response status. After that when we try to send data through the web socket, it does not reach the tomcat instance.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Below is the section of configuration used for websockets from the httpd.config file.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

ProxyPass wss://apache/ws/connect ws://tomcatinstance/wsapp/connect
ProxyPassReverse wss://apache/ws/connect ws://tomcatinstance/wsapp/connect
```